# omniauth custom request phase form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am trying to write a custom OmniAuth strategy.  This needs to prompt for a username and password.  The https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Strategy-Contribution-Guide is a useful start, and I am currently using the OmniAuth::Form method mentioned in the document, but now I want to implement a better login form.

The document says `OmniAuth has a very simple form builder built into it so that you can easily prompt the user for information that's needed for your strategy. These forms are really not meant to be shown to end users but rather work as a stopgap for developers until they implement custom forms...` but it does not say how to go about implementing a custom form.

How do I do it?  Is there a good example?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [OmniAuth wiki](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Dynamic-Providers), you just need to provide a `:form` option when you specify the Rack middleware to use:

```
use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :example, :form => SessionsController.action(:new)
end
```